# Is PyOTA Sandbox up?

Tags: pyota, sandbox

As I'm reading on this guide (http://pyota.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#getting-started)
one should be able to connect to the Sandbox network to test an application.
But as I try to ping the related url ('https://sandbox.iotatoken.com/api/v1/') it doesn't seem to exist
If it isn't up anymore, how can I test my applications? I've read about making transactions with value '0', but it seems pretty slow

Comment: Keep an eye on https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.py/issues/170 for updates on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Sandbox is indeed down, and as a replacement the [PoWbox](https://blog.iota.org/relaunching-the-powbox-d392236b6939) has recently been launched.

While the Sandbox used to be its own IOTA testnet isolated from the normal public testnet, the PoWbox is an addition to the public testnet that can be used to reduce the PoW load for your prototypes you are testing (which are running on the public testnet). So you essentially are [using the normal testnet](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/985/is-there-a-testing-environment-for-dev-purposes/1002#1002) (which does not need any kind of API token) but can also get the PoW advantages that you had on the sandbox.